# What does "Check the diagonal" mean in the lyrics to Freedom by Rage Against The Machine?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I never understood what exactly was meant by:

> Brotha, did ya forget ya name?
>   Did ya lose it on the wall
>   Playin'
>   tic-tac-toe?
>
> Yo, check the diagonal
>   Three brothers gone  Come on
>   Doesn't that
>   make it three in a row?

Is he referencing the tic-tac-toe board?  And why would he lose his name on a wall playing tic-tac-toe?  I loved this disc when it came out, but even back then I had no "street cred" so a lot of these types of references are lost on me.

Comment: I always assumed that it was the diagonal of the board (as per "Doesn't that make it three in a row?"), and that the idea of losing your identity segued into the idea of losing a game. Tic tac toe does seem an unusual metaphor - I would be interested to see if anyone has any more ideas as to the reason!

Comment: From the commercial for "Connect Four"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN3nohBw_CE

Comment: Checking the diagonal is (also) something you do in carpentry, especially in framing up a new wall, where you measure both diagonals across some rectangle you've constructed (e.g. the whole wall) and compare measurements; if the measurements match, then the rectangle is "square", i.e. it has right angles at each of its corners instead of being "racked" one way or another to form a non-square parallelogram.  I don't know enough about the song in question to even suggest whether this has some relation to the surrounding context of those lyrics, but anyway it's another meaning of that expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but it sounds like the person being addressed is keeping track of deaths on the wall.  To the speaker, it looks like a tic-tac-toe game.

My theory is that the first time through, he's talking to a small time gang member who has killed three people.  The second time, he's addressing someone or something bigger --something big enough to kill three million.

It's a critical statement.  After three in a row, the singer thinks the person being addressed has "lost" the game.